# Properties of a matrix with the minimal polynomial $m_A(t) = t^3+2t^2+t+1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Note: A is a 9 by 9 matrix over the rationals.

The question asks if $A$ is diagonizable over the rationals, which it isn't because it's easy to check that $A$ has no rational roots and therefore rational eigenvalues.

$A$ is diagonizable over the complex numbers because in that field there exist 3 distinct eigenvalues for $A$.

Next the quesiton asks me to prove that $A^3 - 5A^2 +4A +3I$ is an invertible matrix. I tried abusing the fact that $A^3 + 2A^2 +A +I = 0$, but didn't really get anywhere. Is solving this as simple as showing that none of the eigenvalues are $0$?

Lastly, the question asks me for the trace and determinant of $A$. I know how to get to them from the characteristic polynomial of $A$, but I have no idea how to get there from the minimal polynomial.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the minimal polynomial to get:
$A^3 - 5A^2 + 4A + 3I= A^3 + 2A^2 + A + I - 7A^2 + 3A + 2I = - 7A^2 + 3A + 2I $, now the latter is a second degree polynomial, so it can't be zero (since the minimal polynomial is of degree 3), then the matrix $- 7A^2 + 3A + 2I$ is invertible and so $A^3 - 5A^2 + 4A + 3I$ is too.

Comment: I might be missing something, but why would the fact that the matrix isn't 0 be enough to say that it's invertible? Why can't it be some other non-zero non-invertible matrix?

Comment: Yes, but it is much easier to check that $-7A^2+3A+2I$ is invertible, which also implies the other is invertible too.

Comment: The problem is that the matrix $A$ isn't given in the question.

Comment: No, but think whether $\det A=0$ or not. Then if $A$ is invertible then $A^2$ is too, and the rest, and since $-7A^2+3A+2I$ is not 0 and is a sum of invertible matrices, then it is invertible.

Comment: I'm not sure that's necessarily true: $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\2 & 1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\1 & 2\end{bmatrix} != 0$$ and isn't invertible.

Comment: Mm you are right! Good example. One should think why this is not the case.. $A(-7A+3)$ is invertible, and then $A(-7A+3)+2I$ should also be it and I guess what you wrote cannot happen in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is solving this as simple as showing that none of the eigenvalues are 0?

Yes it is. The fact that a matrix is invertible iff $0$ is not an eigenvalue is a fact which is independent of the field. All invertibility requires is that the determinant is a unit. Since we are in a field, that's equivalent to requiring non-zero determinant, which is in turn equivalent to requiring that $0$ is not an eigenvalue.

Let $B = A^3 - 5A^2 + 4A + 3I = -7A^2 + 4A + 2I$. Let $f(x) = -7x^2 + 4x + 2$. Note that the eigenvalues of $B$ are precisely $f(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Therefore $B$ will be singular if and only if $f$ and $m_A$ share a root, which we can easily check that they do not. Therefore $B$ is invertible.

> Lastly, the question asks me for the trace and determinant of A. I know how to get to them from the characteristic polynomial of A, but I have no idea how to get there from the minimal polynomial.

This is a good point. Indeed, the minimal polynomial does not typically determine the trace or determinant of a matrix. In this case however, we can actually recover the characteristic polynomial from the minimal polynomial.

Note that your minimal polynomial splits over $\mathbb{C}$ as
$$m_A(x) = (x-\lambda)(x-\mu)(x-\overline{\mu})$$
where $\lambda$ is a real irrational number and where $\mu$ and $\overline{\mu}$ are complex conjugate root pairs. Your characteristic polynomial must be composed of these irreducible terms as well.
$$\chi_A(x) = (x-\lambda)^a[(x-\mu)(x-\overline{\mu})]^b$$
where $a,b\ge 1$ and the degree of the polynomial is $9$. Note that the complex conjugate terms must appear together due to the conjugate root theorem.

But importantly, your characteristic polynomial is a rational polynomial. The only possibility for these terms to combine into a polynomial with rational terms is for the characteristic polynomial to comprise of $3$ copies of the minimal polynomial (you can check case by case, but there is also a more rigorous argument involving a bit of field theory if you're interested):
$$\chi_A(x) = [m_A(x)]^3$$
All of this is just a consequence that your minimal polynomial is *irreducible* as a rational polynomial.

For a perhaps more familiar example, if your matrix were complex and your minimal polynomial was $(x-\lambda)$, then you automatically know that your characteristic polynomial is $(x-\lambda)^n$. This is the same sort of idea.

Knowing your characteristic polynomial, you can easily recover your determinant and your trace.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Why is "Note that the eigenvalues of B are precisely f(λ) where λ is an eigenvalue of A."  true? Does it stem from the fact that if $z$ is an eigenvalue of A, then $z^i$ is an eigenvalue of $A^i$?

Comment: @Jack You can triangularize your matrix over $\mathbb{C}$. Then your eigenvalues appear on your diagonal. If you apply a polynomial to your triangular form, then you see the eigenvalues are transformed accordingly by the polynomial. Generally, if $\sigma$ is the spectrum of your matrix $A$, then $f(\sigma)$ is the spectrum of $f(A)$ for any polynomial $f$.